# Perl LWP close connection manually

Tags: perl, tomcat, lwp, basic-authentication, lwp-useragent

**New Question:**

I'm doing the following with my Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP 5.64;

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$browser->credentials( 
'localhost:8080', 
'Tomcat Manager Application', 
'admin' => '123' 
);

my $app_url  = qq(http://localhost:8080/manager/list);
my $response = $browser->get( $app_url ); #this starts the Tomcat Manager Application
#do something
#end the tomcat manager application / terminate the session
```

Is there a way to end the session? The default session timeout for my Manager Application is 30 minutes. What I've tried is:

```
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$browser->conn_cache(LWP::ConnCache->new());
```

But it still opens a new session always.

I think changing `$browser->timeout` is not the right approach here because I need to terminate the session after I already received the response.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

**Old Question:**

Is there a way to end my session manually using LWP? I have something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP 5.64;

my $app_url = 'htpp://localhost:8080/manager/list'
my $base_url = 'http://localhost:8080'

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$browser->credentials( 
 'localhost:8080/manager/list',
 'Tomcat Manager Application', 
 'admin' => '123' 
);

my $response = $browser->get( $base_url ); #session does not remain open
my $respuesta = $browser->get( $app_url ); #session remains opened 
#do some processing
#and now close the connection
```

I want to run my script many consecutive times and after a while I have a million open sessions on the server.

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: I pull up https://metacpan.org/module/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm and search for "connection". The first hit mentions something about keep_alive and a connection cache. I have a feeling, this might help.

Comment: Is your script still running? As far as I know, LWP::UA doesn't keep persistent connections unless you specifically request it to in the options hash to the new constructor.  I'll assume that the script is running on linux, can you do a `netstat -lnp | grep 8080` and see if a) there are perl/script processes running connected to port 8080, and b) what the status of that socket is? (ie.. CLOSE_WAIT, CONNECTED, etc).

Comment: Thank you. I think this could be HTTP basic auth issue? AFAIK basic auth does not support a "log out". My assumption was that a exit in perl will kill my connection, but i was wrong. Also this is running on a windows machine. I'm fairly sure it has to do with HTTP basic auth since a simple GET to the base URL does not keep the session open. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout for your connections:

```
$browser->timeout([$secs])
```

By default the timeout is 180 secs. You can specify a smaller value and connections will be closed faster.

Comment: this is strange, but try my second option ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
my $response = $browser->get( $base_url ); #session does not remain open
my $respuesta = $browser->get( $app_url ); #session remains opened 
if($respuesta->is_success){
    #do some processing
    die "OK";
}
return 1;
```

Comment: thanks dmitry, i appreciate it. But it still isn't working. I really think its a HTTP Basic auth / Tomcat problem. I tried timeout and the above mentioned keep_alive option but both times it wouldn't work. Basically what I'm doing is i start a Tomcat Application with my Perl script and I don't know how to close it. Executing my Script will open a new session every time. I was hoping that passing keep_alive will fix that